# Predicate or noun after "nationality"

Tags: grammaticality, phrasing

Which one is correct?

To put a predicate after *nationality*

> His nationality is Chinese.

To put a noun after *nationality*

> His nationality is China.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confusing, perhaps because 'china' is used both as a noun and an adjective.

As a noun, it relates to either China as a country, or china (as porcelain).

Here, as 'nationality' is a noun, you need to use an adjective if you want to modify or qualify it - hence 'Chinese' is correct and 'China' isn't. Here, the sense is a direct reference to 'China' as a country.

When 'china' is used as an adjective, it is only ever in the sense of 'a china doll' or 'their china anniversary' - relating to the sense of 'porcelain'.

Comment: How about if his nationality was of the United States of America? what would you say? His nationality is .?. It can't be 'American' because that includes any one of many countries, north and south.

Comment: @WS2 *His nationality is American*; that term may be ambiguous in some European languages, but is not in English. But by the same token, what English lacks is a demonymic adjective for the Americas; we can say North American or South American to indicate the continents rather than the nationality, but there is no term that combines both (Western Hemispherian?).

Comment: @WS2 Unfortunately, we citizens of the US have largely co-opted the term *American* for most usages. If you say someone is *American*, most people would assume US citizenship (or at least long term residency). Unfair, illogical, but common.

Comment: @WS2 Sorry, we flag waving, gun toting, SUV driving, latte sipping, gay marriage banning Americans have taken the term for ourselves.  South Americans and Canadians be damned!  (If it is unclear, my tone is tongue in cheek!)

Comment: @choster I know what you mean. Whenever I have tried to use the term 'North America' intending it to be a collective of Canada and the United States, I have known people assume I was talking about the northern states of the United States. What is an unequivocal way of saying North America without encountering that problem? Do Americans themselves use the term 'North America' in the way they would use 'South America'?

Comment: Within the US, *North American* refers to continental North America (i.e. the landmass north of the Panama Canal) or cultural North America (Canada and the US) or economic North America (NAFTA). There is no geographic term for the "northern" United States, as the country is horizontally oriented; we have the Northeast (New England + Mid-Atlantic), the Great Lakes and Upper Midwest, and the Pacific Northwest. Historically, "the North" encompasses the Midwest and the Northeast, distinguishing it from the West and the South, and their frontier- and Civil War-related cultural connotations.

Answer (score 1):

*Nationality* is a characteristic. When a copular verb is used, it is expressed as an adjective. *Country of origin* is a place, and is expressed as noun.